# Using curl to render and return a pdf-file from jsreport

Tags: jsreport

I'm trying to understand how to use [jsreport][1] in node.js.

Is it possible to get and save the pdf-file using curl?

I couldn't find any documentation in my jsreport installation and on the website. This is very unusual for a RESTful library, I'd expected a couple curl examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, this seems to work:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -k -X  POST https://127.0.0.1/api/report -d"{\"template\": { \"shortid\" : \"NkerYDOXusdf\" }}" > report.pdf
```